# What is "csci" (Paypal)

Tags: c#, json, paypal

I'm trying to create a httpclient that will login to paypal and checkout with token example: EC-72W98000K01165117.
When i use browser to make a payment and use Fiddler to catch request, this is my browser request

```
{
"meta": {
    "token": "EC-72W98000K01165117",
    "calc": "7b55bc20cca9d",
    "csci": "7a4236636ffd49dc934eb73da4402f49",
    "locale": {
        "country": "US",
        "language": "en"
    },
    "state": "ui_checkout_review",
    "app_name": "hermesnodeweb"
}}
```

I don't know where "csci": "7a4236636ffd49dc934eb73da4402f49" come from :(

Answer (score 1):

After digging into this api to write an automation suite, it turned out the csci is just a UUID (Universally Unique Identifier).  Any 32 digit hexadecimal value in the request should work, as long as that identifier has not previously been used.  Any method of randomly generating these will suffice, but the JavaScript code which generates this on the page is:

```
  // See https://github.com/broofa/node-uuid for API details
  function v4(options, buf, offset) {
    // Deprecated - 'format' argument, as supported in v1.2
    var i = buf && offset || 0;

    if (typeof options === 'string') {
      buf = options === 'binary' ? new BufferClass(16) : null;
      options = null;
    }
    options = options || {};

    var rnds = options.random || (options.rng || _rng)();

    // Per 4.4, set bits for version and `clock_seq_hi_and_reserved`
    rnds[6] = rnds[6] & 0x0f | 0x40;
    rnds[8] = rnds[8] & 0x3f | 0x80;

    // Copy bytes to buffer, if provided
    if (buf) {
      for (var ii = 0; ii < 16; ii++) {
        buf[i + ii] = rnds[ii];
      }
    }

    return buf || unparse(rnds);
  }
```